# Apply unique styles to each <li> in an ng-repeat list in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to angular and I am having some difficulty wrapping my head around how to handle certain things "the Angular way". Please forgive my ignorance in this post.

I currently have 6 list items that are created by hitting a data source and using `ng-repeat`.

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="vote.Score = vote.Score + 1">
    {{ vote.Id | covertToName }} has a score of {{ vote.Score }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Each of these list items has a "progress bar" below it which is simply a absolutely positioned `:after` psuedo element. My aim is to increase the width of the progress bar's `:after` psuedo element when you click on the list item to give you a visual display of the number of votes each element has.

I need a way to apply a custom style (`width:`) to each of the list items created by the `ng-repeat` when a user clicks on a list item. For example, if a user clicks on John Doe and his Score is currently at 50, I need his progress bar to assume a width of 51px as well as apply the score pixel width to all other list items.

Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

**Edit: I am using SCSS and I have no control over the JSON data source.**

Comment: `ng-style="{'width':'51px'}"` See [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

Comment: I went down this route but the styles need to be applied to an `:after` pseudo element, not the span itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a CSS preprocessor like SASS you can easily achieve this by using `ng-class="progress"`. `progress` would hold a string like `progress-51`.

The SASS-code

```
$class-slug: progress !default

@for $i from 0 through 100
    .#{$class-slug}-#{$i}:after
        width: 0px + $i
```

would emit

```
.progress-0:after {
    width: 0px;
}
.progress-1:after {
    width: 1px;
}
...
.progress-100:after {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I am currently using SCSS so this is definitely a viable solution. Let me do some digging into this and get back to you. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

```
li:first-child:after { /*styles*/ }
li:second-child:after { /*styles*/ }
li:third-child:after { /*styles*/ }
li:fourth-child:after { /*styles*/ }
li:fifth-child:after { /*styles*/ }
li:sixth-child:after { /*styles*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact pixels based of values I dont think classes is really useful since you don't know what element need what style. Perhaps you can use inline styles for this even though it is not best practise.

Example:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-click="vote.Score = vote.Score + 1">
    <span style="width:{{vote.score}}px;>{{ vote.Id | covertToName }} has a score of {{ vote.Score }}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I considered doing this but I need to apply the styles to the psuedo element `:after`, not the span itself. This can't be done inline since inline styling is direct target of the element itself.

Comment: He could very well use classes like `progress-51`. CSS preprocessors like SASS make it pretty easy to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

mm.. u can create attrib in object votes, like this:

```
var votes = [{Id:0,Score:0,width:"first"},{Id:1,Score:0,width:"second"},{Id:2,Score:0,width:"third"}];
```

And then u can use ng-class to do a unique style each li:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="vote in votes" ng-class="vote.width" vote.ng-click="vote.Score = vote.Score + 1">
    {{ vote.Id | covertToName }} has a score of {{ vote.Score }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and need define this styles:

```
.second {
  width: 50%;
  background:red;
}
.first {
  width: 20%;
  background: blue;
}
.third {
  width: 30%;
  background: orange;
}
```